# Is the db.commit() so that you don't edit the database many times just once?

Tags: web2py

Consider this table

```
db.define_table( 'people' , Field( 'name' ) )
```

My understanding is that I can update records in a database like this:

option 1:

```
for row in db( db.people ).select():
    row.update_record( name='Bob' )
```

option 2:

```
for row in db( db.people ).select( id ):
    db( db.people.id == row.id ).update( name='Bob' )
db.commit()
```

What is the difference? Does the `.commit()` command basically do all the changes at once thus blocking database access during that duration of updates? While **option 1** updates each record at a time thus in the time in between it could be concievable that the db gets written between `update_record` commands?

It is my (possibly incorrect) understanding that `db.commit()` is needed if the above code (option 2) is placed in a module rather than the controller, hence the `db.commit()` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

web2py wraps each HTTP request in a database transaction. If there is an exception during the request, the transaction will be rolled back. Otherwise, at the end of the request, just before returning the response, the transaction is committed (so all insert/update operations will be committed at that time).

If you explicitly call `db.commit()` in the application code, then the transaction will be committed immediately rather than waiting until the end of the request. Any subsequent operations will be part of a new transaction.

In both cases above, all of the updates will be committed at the same time. The only difference is that in the first case, the commit will be issued by the framework right before returning the HTTP response (assuming there is no intervening exception that triggers a rollback), and in the second case, the commit happens immediately after running through the loop of updates.

In option 2, if you moved the `db.commit()` call inside the loop, then the updates would indeed be committed one at a time rather than all at once.

Also, note that to update a record, you do not need to first select it, and if you want to apply the same update to many records, you don't need to update one record at a time but would instead apply the update to a DAL Set object representing all the records:

```
db(db.people.id > 0).update(name='Bob')
```

The above defines a set of records in the `db.people` table (in this case, all the records) and then updates the "name" field of all of those records. This operation does not involve any records being selected from the database.

Comment: thank you, I'm a bit confused. Are you saying option 1 and option 2 are equivalent? I thought that `row.update_record` commits the changes instantly while `set.update` waits until the `db.commit()` whether it's due to the controller or a manual one like my example. Also, yup I'm aware of the multiple update method you suggest but in my real case each record is updated with it's own value.

Comment: No, `row.update_record` does not commit immediately. Perhaps you are referring to the distinction between `row.update` and `row.update_record`. The former updates the `row` object itself but has no effect on the database record, whereas the latter updates the database (but the actual update doesn't get committed until the end of the request).